# Why rabbit is suprisingly slow?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, easynetq

I'm trying to implement messanging through the RabbitMQ. I always heard that it's crazily fast so I gave it a try. But for some reason, It's very slow.

I have one queue called `blockchain`. It has several messages, message size is about ~1kb. Then I create a queue listener which basically just write a constant text in stdout:

```
public async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{ 
    // using EasyNetQ in this example.
    using (var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(_queueSettings.RabbitConnection)).Advanced)
    {
        using (var _ = await ConsumeBus(bus, _queueSettings.QueueName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Listening for messages. Hit <return> to quit.");

            cancellationToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}

private async Task<IDisposable> ConsumeBus(IAdvancedBus bus, string queueName)
{
    var queue = await bus.QueueDeclareAsync(queueName, true).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return bus.Consume(queue,
                       (body, properties, info) => Console.WriteLine("Got a message!"));
}
```

But when I watch at the queue I see that message consumption speed is only ***~40 msg/sec***. Comparing to 50k msg/sec [written in articles](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2018-01-08-part2-rabbitmq-best-practice-for-high-performance.html) over the net it seems to be very slow. When I go to the management page I see that queue is almost completely utilized:

[image]

Connection string seems to be ok too, we take large batches and process them:

```
"QueueSettings": {
    "RabbitConnection":
        "host=myhost:5672;username=reader;password=readerpass5;requestedHeartbeat=20;prefetchcount=100;timeout=1000;publisherConfirms=true",
    "QueueName": "blockchain"
},
```

What's wrong here? How could I get this amazing number of thousands messages per second per queue? Should I deploy 1000 consumers and expect that they would have 40*1000 msg/sec?

---

This version is slighly faster, however, I still unable to get more than 50 msg/sec

```
public async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var factory = GetConnectionFactory()
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        using (var _ = ConsumeBus(channel, _queueSettings.QueueName))
        {
            _contextlessLogger.Information("Listening for messages. Hit <return> to quit.");

            cancellationToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}

private IDisposable ConsumeBus(IModel bus, string queueName)
{
    return new Consumer(bus, queueName, async bytes => Console.WriteLine("Got a message!"));
}

public class Consumer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IModel _channel;
    private readonly Func<byte[], Task> _action;
    private readonly EventingBasicConsumer _consumer;

    public Consumer(IModel channel, string queueName, Func<byte[], Task> action)
    {
        _channel = channel;
        _action = action;
        _consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        _consumer.Received += OnReceived;
        channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, _consumer);
    }

    private async void OnReceived(object model, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea)
    {
        try
        {
            await _action(ea.Body);
            _channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
        }
        catch
        {
            _channel.BasicNack(ea.DeliveryTag, false, true);
        }
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        _consumer.Received -= OnReceived;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me you only consume one message.  Rejigger this so you call CreateBus() only once, Consume() many times.

Comment: @HansPassant no, it's how messages get handled https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/The-Advanced-API#consuming .

Comment: For those who downvote: you see anything harmful here? What's wrong with the question for you?

Comment: Can you try to do something else than Console.WriteLine("Got a message!")? 
I think that might be a bottleneck, can you try to log to something else?

Comment: @WiebeTijsma no, empty handler has exactly same behavior. Beside that, `stdout` can easily handle more than 40 calls per second anyway.

Comment: Since we don't know much about your environment, and do not have a complete copy of your code, nor know what version of RabbitMQ and Erlang you are using, there's not much that can be suggested. The RabbitMQ team provides [PerfTest](https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-tools.html#throughput-load-testing), which is an application you can run to performance-test your RabbitMQ installation. If it shows acceptable performance, you know the issue is in your code.

Comment: @LukeBakken it's complete code sample, except for `_queueSettings` which is basically a DTO with settings. My environment is just a PC with 16gb ram and i7 CPU. Rabbit `v3.7.0` Erlang `v19.3.6.5`

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy - I can't copy your code, compile and run it, therefore it is not complete. If you can provide something that compiles and runs, preferably via a git repository somewhere, I could help out. Did you run PerfTest to see what the theoretical performance of your PC is?

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy Do you have a HDD or SSD? And I assume you run Consumer and RabbitMQ locally on you PC?
Also, try increasing the prefetch size in your connection string.

Comment: @FredrikClaesson I'm using SSD, of course. I'm going to post a complete example, just need couple of days for it.